# How to create function that get value from Promise.prototype.then()

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to create function that get value from Promise.prototype.then(), but I don't exactly know how it's works.

I have such code:

```
ConfigurationPage.filteredItems.getText().then(function(value){console.log(value)});
```

and in console log I get some value - it's OK.

I try to create function that looks like this:

```
function getValue(data) {
return data.then(function(value){value})}
```

My expected result when I call such function:

```
getValue(ConfigurationPage.filteredItems.getText())
```

I get a value.

But I don't know how to create right function.

Thanks for support.

Comment: Do you understand well the difference between asynchronous and synchronous code? Well, this is it - you can't really do it the way you would expect. I'm closing it as duplicate, check the duplicate question it will explain everything in details.

Comment: Normally in such cases I merely climb into my time machine and visit the future to find the value.

Comment: :-)
Ok, guys.
I understood my mistake. Thanks for help.